# use icon in bootstrap vue table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

i have this array for data of my table in bootstrap-vue and my problem is i want to use icon in my table but when i use something like this shows me '' in  string and browser doesnt render icon . what is the solution for this problem??

```
items:[
{isActive: true,isMember: '<font-awesome-icon icon="user-secret" />',registerCounter: 4},
{isActive: true,isMember: '<font-awesome-icon icon="user-secret" />',registerCounter: 4},
]
```

and this is my table tag:

```
<b-table :items="items"></b-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because the data is escaped meaning the HTML in the data has no effect and the font-awesome-icon component will never be rendered. You could use v-html, but that is not very secure and I don't think components render in v-html (I never tried it)? Probably the best solution to this is using scoped slots.

**[Click here for codepen example](https://codepen.io/sigfriedseldeslachts/pen/JQrEwZ)**

Docs: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#custom-data-rendering.

```html
<b-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
    <template slot="isMember" slot-scope="{ item: { isMember }}">
        <i :class="'fas ' + isMember"></i>
        <!-- You can also use the font-awesome-icon component here -->
    </template>
</b-table>
```

The only thing you need to do apart from that is having your data as follows:

```js
fields: [
  'isActive',
  'registerCounter',
  // This one needs a custom template, so we define the key and the label
  { key: 'isMember', label: 'Is Member' }
],
items: [
  { isActive: true, isMember: 'fa-user-secret', registerCounter: 4 },
  { isActive: true, isMember: 'fa-user-secret', registerCounter: 4 },
]
```

Hope this helps.